# Error code 1215, cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a quick question here about a database I'm trying to implement. I have referred to several other questions similar to mine, but they don't quite answer my specific question.

I'm relatively new to using SQL, I've taken one class in it a while ago, so I may just need a duh! kind of refresher here.

When I try to build this database using MySQL, I'm not able to create any of my tables because of an error saying "Error code 1215, cannot add foreign key constraint"

Am I just missing something obvious?

Below is my SQL:

```
create database emp;
use emp;

select database ();

create table employee
(Fname varchar (15), 
 Minit varchar (1),
 Lname varchar (15), 
 Ssn int (9) not null, 
 Bdate varchar (10), 
 Address varchar (40),
 Sex varchar (1),
 Salary varchar (10), 
 Super_ssn varchar (9),
 Dno int (1), 

 primary key(Ssn),

 foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn),
 foreign key(Dno) references department(Dnumber)


)

Engine=INNODB;

create table department
(Dname varchar (15), 
Dnumber int (1) not null, 
Mgr_ssn int (9), 
Mgr_start_date varchar (15),

primary key(Dnumber), 

foreign key(Mgr_ssn) references employee (Ssn) 


)

Engine=INNODB;


create table dept_locations
(Dnumber int (1) not null,
Dlocation varchar (15) not null,

primary key(Dnumber, Dlocation),
foreign key(Dnumber) references department(Dnumber)

)

Engine=INNODB; 

create table project
(Pname varchar (15), 
 Pnumber int (3) not null, 
 Plocation varchar (15), 
 Dnum int (1),

 primary key(Pnumber),
 foreign key(Dnum) references department(Dnumber)

 )

 Engine=INNODB;

 create table works_on
 (Essn int (9) not null, 
  Pno int (3) not null,
  hours float (4),

  primary key(Essn, Pno), 
  foreign key (Essn) references employee(Ssn),
  foreign key(Pno) references project (Pnumber)
  )

  Engine=INNODB;

  create table dependent 

  (Essn int (9) not null, 
   Dependent_name varchar (15) not null, 
   Sex varchar (1), 
   Bdate varchar (10),
   Relationship varchar (10),

   primary key(Essn, Dependent_Name),
   foreign key (Essn) references employee(Ssn)

   )

   Engine=INNODB;
```

Comment: Which create table statement is actually the one which is failing?

Comment: Every single one, but the first one I started with is employee.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a foreign key that references another table before you create the other table. So you can't have a foreign key in `employee` that refers to `department` before you create the `department` table. But since the `department` table has a foreign key that references `employee`, you can't create them in the opposite order, either.

When you create the tables, leave out the foreign keys that refer to tables you haven't created yet, then add them later with `ALTER TABLE`.

```
create table employee
(Fname varchar (15), 
 Minit varchar (1),
 Lname varchar (15), 
 Ssn int (9) not null, 
 Bdate varchar (10), 
 Address varchar (40),
 Sex varchar (1),
 Salary varchar (10), 
 Super_ssn varchar (9),
 Dno int (1), 

 primary key(Ssn),
 foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn),
);

create table department
(Dname varchar (15), 
Dnumber int (1) not null, 
Mgr_ssn int (9), 
Mgr_start_date varchar (15),

primary key(Dnumber),
foreign key(Mgr_ssn) references employee (Ssn) 
);

alter table employee add constraint foreign key (Dno) references department(Dnumber);
```

Comment: Oh wow. This is what I believed was happening. Thank you so much for answering. How can I use the alter table function you're speaking of?

Comment: It's in the answer.

Comment: I meant like what syntax would I use to add a foreign key with alter table

Comment: I used this, but got the same error:                                                                             alter table employee add foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn);

Comment: You don't need that, it's already in the `CREATE TABLE`. You only need to use `ALTER TABLE` to add foreign keys pointing to tables you're going to create after.